# What are the units of the half life in exponential decay?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis, si-units, half-life

I have tried to look up how to determine the units of the half life of an exponential decay, but I keep reading its 'time'. I am well aware it's time. I'm not aware of the specific units of time, is it seconds, minutes, days, years?

I didn't give much context but if someone could give me a generic answer / reference that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Commonly, as the base unit of time in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units is the second, they are expressed in this unit. But it's up to you, you can choose the time unit you think is more suitable for your problem/situation.

Comment: Experimentally , you take  N number of decaying elements  and start your stop watch, and stop your stop watch when the remaining intact elements are N/2 .  That is why everybody answers that the units are relevant to the  system you are studying. Time in some units, from picoseconds to light years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of undecayed nuclei (or whatever) at a time $t$ is given by:

$$ N = N_0\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{t/t_{1/2}} \tag{1} $$

Where $t_{1/2}$ is the half life. The exponent must be dimensionless so the ratio $t/t_{1/2}$ must be dimensionless, and that means the units of $t$ and $t_{1/2}$ must be the same.

So you can use whatever units you want for $t_{1/2}$ provided you use the same units for $t$. For example the half life of uranium 238 is normally given as 4.5 billion years. You can plug this value into equation (1) provided the units of $t$ are years as well. Generally speaking we use whatever units are most convenient, though the advice for beginners is that if you are uncertain always use the SI units, which in this case would be seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The unit is usually seconds. But it really depends on the situation you are in. If you are talking about uranium-238, then you'll be talking about a half life in the billions of years. However, if you are talking about the half-life of a muon, then it'll be in seconds or microseconds.

Comment: For ${}^{14}C$, its half-life is $5,730 \pm 40 \,$ years.